# Estoy intentando hacer una calculadora pero el resultado no se muestra sino hasta que presione 2 veces el igual

Tags: javascript, reactjs, operador, usestate

Estoy intentando programar mi primera calculadora en React pero el estado no se actualiza sino hasta presionar 2 veces cualquier boton

por el momento estoy probando con el + pero no se actualiza hasta despues de tocar 2 veces el simbolo "="

Estuve revisando el codigo con console.log pero el simbolo de + y de = no me dan el resultado deseado sino hasta que los presiono dos veces no se si es algo con el estado de react pero no se me actualiza a la primera

Al presionar el mas 1 el console.log de el case "+" me muestra "string 0 2" el estado actual sin modificacion pero no me muestra el estado que estoy intentando cambiar en el useState del case "+" ya al presionar el "+" por segunda vez el muestra "number 2 0" el resultado que quiero lo mismo con el case "="

este es el codigo:

```
export default class Calculator extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

this.state = {
  display: "0",
  operator: "",
  firstNumber: "",
  secondNumber: "",
  result: "",
};


 }

  ChangeDisplay = (value) => {
    const { display } = this.state;
    if (display === "0") {
      this.setState({
        display: value,
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        display: display + value,
      });
    }
  };



Calculate = (operator) => {
    const { firstNumber, secondNumber } = this.state;
    let result = "";
    switch (operator) {
      case "+":
        this.setState({
          firstNumber: parseInt(this.state.display),
          result: this.state.display,
          display: "0",
          operator: operator,
        });
        console.log(typeof firstNumber, firstNumber, this.state.display);
        break;

  case "-":
    break;

  case "*":
    break;

  case "/":
    break;
  case "=":

    this.setState({
      secondNumber: this.state.display,
    });
    console.log(secondNumber);
    if (this.state.operator === "+") {
      result = parseFloat(firstNumber) + parseFloat(secondNumber);
      this.setState({
        result: result,
      });
    } else if (this.state.operator === "-") {
      result = parseFloat(firstNumber) - parseFloat(secondNumber);
      this.setState({
        result: result,
      });
    } else if (this.state.operator === "*") {
      result = parseFloat(firstNumber) * parseFloat(secondNumber);
      this.setState({
        result: result,
      });
    } else if (this.state.operator === "/") {
      result = parseFloat(firstNumber) / parseFloat(secondNumber);
      this.setState({
        result: result,
      });
    }
    break;

  case "C":
    this.setState({
      display: "0",
      firstNumber: "0",
      secondNumber: "0",
      result: "0",
    });
    break;
  default:
    break;
}


};

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="CalculatorBox">
          <div className="CalculatorBox-display">
            <div className="CalculatorBox-display-screen">
              <div className="CalculatorBox-display-screen-text">
                <span>({this.state.result})</span>
                <span>{this.state.display}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="Keypad">
            <div className="KeypadRow">
              <button
                className="KeypadButton"
                onClick={() => this.ChangeDisplay("1")}
              >
                1
              </button>
              <button
                className="KeypadButton"
                onClick={() => this.ChangeDisplay("2")}
              >
                2
              </button>
              <button
                className="KeypadButton"
                onClick={() => this.ChangeDisplay("3")}
              >
                3
              </button>
              <button
                className="KeypadButton"
                onClick={() => this.Calculate("+")}
              >
                +
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="KeypadRow">
              <button
                className="KeypadButton"
                onClick={() => this.ChangeDisplay("4")}
              >
                4
              </button>
              <button
                className="KeypadButton"
                onClick={() => this.ChangeDisplay("5")}
              >
                5
              </button>
              <button
                className="KeypadButton"
                onClick={() => this.ChangeDisplay("6")}
              >
                6
              </button>
              <button className="KeypadButton">-</button>
            </div>
            <div className="KeypadRow">
              <button
                className="KeypadButton"
                onClick={() => this.ChangeDisplay("7")}
              >
                7
              </button>
              <button
                className="KeypadButton"
                onClick={() => this.ChangeDisplay("8")}
              >
                8
              </button>
              <button
                className="KeypadButton"
                onClick={() => this.ChangeDisplay("9")}
              >
                9
              </button>
              <button className="KeypadButton">*</button>
            </div>
            <div className="KeypadRow">
              <button className="KeypadButton">.</button>
              <button
                className="KeypadButton"
                onClick={() => this.ChangeDisplay("0")}
              >
                0
              </button>
              <button
                className="KeypadButton"
                onClick={() => this.Calculate("=")}
              >
                =
              </button>
              <button className="KeypadButton">/</button>
            </div>
            <div className="KeypadRow">
              <button
                className="KeypadButton"
                onClick={() => this.Calculate("C")}
              >
                C
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que cuando presionas `=` y haces:

```
this.setState({
    secondNumber: this.state.display,
});
```

por la forma en que funciona React, el estado no cambia inmediatamente, por lo tanto en las siguientes líneas, por ejemplo, cuando se va a ejecutar:

```
result = parseFloat(firstNumber) + parseFloat(secondNumber);
```

En ese momento, secondNumber todavía no está actualizado, y sigue teniendo el valor anterior, que es un string vacío `""`.

Por lo tanto, para ejecutar las operaciones, en lugar de usar **secondNumber**, por la forma en que funciona tu código, podrías usar **displayNumber**.

Si quisieras usar **secondNumber**, creo que deberías cambiar como funciona tu función **changeDisplay**, de manera que si ya hay un número en el display, al presionar otro, te lo guarde como **secondNumber**, o algo similar.